# Download a file (zip or jpg) from a webpage

Tags: html, vba, download

I have some issues downloading an image (or zip sometimes) from a webpage.
I've checked a few forums about the topic where most of the time they suggest using the URLDownloadToFile function.
I tried to apply it but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example of the type of webpage I'm dealing with :

[image]

The type here is jpg but sometimes it can be a zip.
For the jpg case, I have two ways to do it:

1. Click on the *View* button, which will open a new webpage containing **1 image only**, selecting that webpage and somehow dowloading the image, which I don't manage to do.
   (There is a "Save Picture As" when you rigth click a picture manually, but how to access to this with VBA ? ) :

   ```
                 objIE.document.frames(1).frames(1).document.getElementById("notPrintable").document.getElementsByName("view")(0).Click 'This clicks on the View Button
                 attachment_url = "https://pumapgf-row.bmwgroup.net/puma/case/showfile.do?selectedIndex=" & elem_id & "&filename=" & elem_name & "%20%7C%20jpg%20%7C%20" & end_url ' this is the url of the new webpage which is opened when I click the view button

                 Set objIE = IEWindowFromLocation(attachment_url) ' I select the new webpage
                 Set IEDoc = objIE.document ' set document on it
   ```

   The html from this new webpage in the case it's a jpg of course) looks like this:[image]
   What I tried to do then but unsuccessfully is to use the URLDownloadToFile function this way

   ```
    Dim myImages As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set myImages = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, myImages(0).href, "P:\Alex\ABC.img", 0, 0)
   ```

   Whether I create or not a such called file before I run the code, it doesn't make any difference. I also tried with .jpg, .img, .png.
   myImages(0).href ends like this :

   [image]

   So I don't know if the fact that .href doesn't end with something like .jpg or .img is an issue.
2. Click on the *Save As* button : valid for both jpg and zip files, so would be a better solution. I manage to click on it of course, but the issue comes from the fact that Internet displays this [image] and I have no idea how to deal with it.

Any idea how to do this ?

EDIT : [Here is the properties window of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLcEf.png)

Comment: Just download it and check to see if the file starts with a jpg header (0xFFD8FFE0) or (0xFFD8FF01).

Comment: Not sure to understand your comment. You can see on the last picture of my post the name attributed to the picture ( starts with UX69525)

Comment: I'm not talking about the filename, I'm talking about the actual binary file that you download.

Comment: How/Where can I actually check this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a valid download URL (which I can't test based on the site in your question), all you should need to do to test if a file is a jpg is to download it and check for the presence of the [JPEG file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure):

```
Public Function FileIsJpg(filepath As String) As Boolean
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open filepath For Binary As #handle
    Dim header As Integer
    Get #handle, , header
    'Note the byte order.
    If header = &HD8FF Then
        Get #handle, , header
        If header = &HE0FF Or header = &H1FF Then
            FileIsJpg = True
        End If
    End If
    Close #handle
End Function
```

Note that for your usage, this will need error handling because of the possibility that `URLDownloadToFile` still has the file open.  I'm assuming that you have some sort of wait mechanism in place (it's a non-blocking function).  If not, you need to either use the native callback mechanisms or take a guess and used `Application.Wait` or something similar.

**Example usage:**

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Const S_OK As Long = 0

Sub Examples()
    Const TestJpgUrl As String = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"
    Const TestPngUrl As String = "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png"

    Dim target As String
    target = Environ$("TEMP") & "\test.png"
    If URLDownloadToFile(0, TestPngUrl, target, 0, 0) = S_OK Then
        'Wait for download to complete - a callback function would be better.
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        MsgBox target & ": " & FileIsJpg(target)
    End If
    Kill target

    target = Environ$("TEMP") & "\test.jpg"
    If URLDownloadToFile(0, TestJpgUrl, target, 0, 0) = S_OK Then
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        MsgBox target & ": " & FileIsJpg(target)
    End If
    Kill target
End Sub
```

Note that you can also explicitly test for [zip files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) in a similar way, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will take me a while to go through it and understand it fully. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok so I applied your code to my case. First  I got False with FileIsJpg so my picture is not a jpg. Then I modified the `If header = &HD8FF Then` with `If header = &H5089 Then` as suggested on this post [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/xiSJeLC_1Ow/-8jsXbwYxegJ] and it still didn't go through so I assume it isn't a png neither...so how does this result help me out in saving my image ?

Comment: @Seb - Set a breakpoint after `Set myImages = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")`.  Then type `?myImages(0).href` in the Immediate Window and hit [Enter].  Copy and paste the result into your browser address bar.  Are you getting a valid file?

Comment: So I did this and got a valid href, when I enter it in the browser it directs me to the image webpage as I mentioned in my post above. The href returned in the immediate window is also shown in my post above.

Comment: If this can help, I editted my post with the properties of the image when I right click on it